# Testing View Controllers --iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ocunit

My question is 2-fold. 1. Can I use OCUnit to test View Controllers. If so, how should I do it? If not, is there another Testing Kit I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely can.  Say you had a UITableViewController, and you wanted to make sure that it had 2 sections with 5 rows each; that is easily done in a test method like so:

```
- (void) testTableHasCorrectRowsAndSections
{
  id tableViewController = [[[YourTableViewControllerSubclass alloc] init] autorelease];

  STAssertEquals(2,[tableViewController numberOfSectionsInTableView:nil],@"");
  STAssertEquals(5,[tableViewController tableView:nil numberOfRowsInSection:0],@"");
  STAssertEquals(5,[tableViewController tableView:nil numberOfRowsInSection:1],@"");
}
```

I would also recommend also utilizing [OCMock](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/OCMock/) to help you with testing your controllers.  you can easily mock a view and ensure that your controller is interacting with it properly.